# Polarization effects of second-harmonic generation (SHG)

Tags: optics, polarization, non-linear-optics

In one of my labs, we were using an Nd:YAG at 1064 nm and we put it through a KTP nonlinear crystal to perform [SHG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation).  We noticed that before the crystal, the 1064 light was unpolarized, but the 532 light was polarized. How does SHG polarize the light?

Comment: IIRC, SHG only takes place because of an asymmetric response, and that only happens in one plane of the crystal. If that's correct, then the other polarization of 1.06x is not frequency-doubled.

Answer (score 3):

Generally in Nd:YAG harmonic generation using KTP, Type-II collinear phase-matching is used, which means that both ordinary and extraordinary polarizations are mixed to form an extraordinary polarized doubled beam. In essence, both polarizations of light in the unpolarized beam are combined to form a polarized beam.

This means that while unpolarized light is input, the resulting wave-mixed beam has a definite polarization pointing along the fast axis.